# Does the forgetful functor from the inner product spaces to vector spaces has a left adjoint?

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory

Let $k$ be a field. I don’t know the conventional notation of the category of inner product spaces over field $k$, donate it $\mathbf{IPrd}_k$ here. The question is, does the functor
$$U: \mathbf{IPrd}_k\to \mathbf{Vect}_k$$
which forgets the inner product structure have a left adjoint?

I suspect if it is possible to define a inner product on each vector space naturally, for if so, one could further define a natural isomorphism from each vector space to its dual. So I guess that either the adjunction doesn’t exist, or the inner product is defined in some vector spaces quite different than the original one.

---

**EDIT:** By the time I asked this question, I didn’t realized that there are underlying troubles as commented below. For clarity, let’s assume that what it meant was that morphisms are linear maps, and $k$ is a subfield of $\mathbb C$.

Of course this is much weaker than the definition of $\mathbf{Hilb}$. I wish to know either

1. the answer to the question, or
2. why this idea doesn’t work.

My apologies for this kinda problematic question.

Comment: What are the morphisms in the category of inner product spaces ? Just linear maps ?

Comment: What's an inner product for a general field?

Comment: If you take morphisms to be linear maps, then the category has already forgotten about the inner product structure! So the forgetful functor $U$ is an equivalence of categories, and has a left adjoint for uninteresting reasons.

Comment: If the morphisms are just linear maps, then the category of inner product spaces is *equivalent* to the category of vector spaces. Indeed, if $\langle\rangle_1$ and $\langle\rangle_2$ are two inner products on $V$, then $(V,\langle\rangle_1)$ is isomorphic to $(V,\langle\rangle_2)$ (the identity map $V\to V$ is an isomorphism!). Then any functor $\mathbf{Vect}_k\to \mathbf{IPrd}_k$ which takes $V$ and equips it with an arbitrary inner product gives you a left adjoint. The point is that if you add structure, but it's not reflected in the morphisms, you don't get anything new categorically.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Ah I see we said the same thing, but you said it more concisely!

Comment: @AlexKruckman "Concise" isn't always better!